# Get corresponding category for sql groupby min and max function SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, mysql-workbench

I have a table t1 with the columns : `TRANSACTION_ID,USER_ID,MERCHANT_NAME,TRANSACTION_DATE,AMOUNT`

a) Write a query to find the first merchant a user transacts on

b) Write a query to find the last merchant a user transacts on

I tried the following query which should work for a)

```
select USER_ID,MERCHANT_NAME,Min(Bill_Date) from t1
Group by customer_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Limit` with `order by` clause

For first query: `order by Bill_Date` will sort the rows in ascending order of Bill_Date then `Limit 1` will return the first row.

```
select USER_ID,MERCHANT_NAME,Bill_Date from t1
Group by customer_id
order by Bill_Date 
Limit 1
```

For second query: `order by Bill_Date desc` will sort the rows in descending order of Bill_Date then `Limit 1` will return the first row in the reverse order of first query.

```
select USER_ID,MERCHANT_NAME,Bill_Date from t1
Group by customer_id
order by Bill_Date desc
Limit 1
```